# Lisp: How to obtain the final loop value?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

```
(defun index-iteration (n) 
  (let ((x 0))
    (loop for j from 0 to n while (< x n) do
      (setf x (max-index-for-iteration j)))))
```

I have the following lisp code, at the end of the loop I want to return the value `j`. I have investigated:

- `collect` but that returns a list of values with the value I want (the last `j` at the end)
- `finally` but it didn't work.
- `return` but it ends the loop early

Comment: If `collect` has your answer at the end, couldn't you just return the last value from it?

Comment: how about using finally together with return?

Comment: You could use a second `setf` to remember the value of `j`. Or you could replace the loop with a recursive function.

Comment: @spiderPig I'm already doing that, but I want cleaner code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to **combine** [`finally`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/06_agb.htm) and [`return`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_return.htm) like this:

```
(loop ...
  finally (return (1- j)))
```

Please note the unfortunate use
of [`1-`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_1pl_1_.htm) which is due to the
fact that the `finally` clause is executed **after** the termination
clause (`while` in your case) transfers control there.
IOW, it requires the knowledge about how the termination clause is handled.

You can stay within the `loop` domain (without the extra `let`) like
this:

```
(loop for j from 0 to n
  for ret = j
  do ...
  finally (return ret))
```

You could also use the [`maximize`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/06_ac.htm) clause:

```
(loop for j from 0 to n ...
  maximize j)
```

but this relies on the knowledge that the final value of `j` was the maximum one.

PS. Note also that you do not need the `while` clause in your `loop`.

Comment: But that doesn't give me the last value of j (as seen with princ), it gives me a value one greater.

Comment: @swissnetizen: oops, sorry, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you might want something like this, but I am unsure:

```
(defun index-iteration (n)
  (loop :for j :from 0 :to n
        :for x := (max-index-for-iteration j)
        :while (<= x n)
        :finally (return (1- j))))
```

There are several things that make this smell like off-by-one: the `to`, the `<=`, and in your question code the fact that `x` is always 0 during the first iteration (what should happen for n = 0?).  Maybe show a bit more context, e. g. `max-index-for-iteration`, or what you want to achieve, for a better answer.